# What is the equivalent of git stash in svn?

Tags: svn, git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Temporarily put away uncommited changes in Subversion (a la “git-stash”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554278/temporarily-put-away-uncommited-changes-in-subversion-a-la-git-stash)

Is there an equivalent to git stash in svn? I am working on a project that uses svn, with which I am less familiar.

Thanks!