# Checking in specific part of code within a file

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

I am trying to check in a specific part of a file into SVN, Example I have a file named Example.cs which is already on SVN in which I have added two new methods but I just want to check in just one method and hold onto the other one for a later time.

**Is this possible?**

Comment: Modify the file to the state in which it should be checked in.  Check it in.  Then make further modifications locally as desired.  It seems kind of silly and error-prone to manually pick and choose lines of code for checking in.  Any given committed revision of the codebase should be complete and compile-able.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a svn patch for storing your second method, and apply the patch for later.

store the patch

`svn diff > patch_name.patch`

Revert your change

`svn revert -R .`

apply the patch

`$ cd /workingcopy`

`$ svn patch /path/to/patch_name.patch`

Reference:

[Temporarily put away uncommited changes in Subversion (a la “git-stash”)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3391053/2802809)

[Using patch as a subversion stash](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/02/using-patch-as-subversion-stash.html)

[svn patch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.patch.html)