# Is there a way to build a signed APK in Android Studio without the uncommitted changes I've made?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, svn, git-svn

I use SVN in Android Studio which tracks the changes I've made compared to the committed copy. Today, I wanted to build an APK for QA without incorporating the changes I've made to some classes that I hadn't committed yet to SVN. Is there a way to make an APK that would ignore the changes or do I have to comment each of the lines I've added/changed out (which is what I did today but seems like there would be a better solution)?

Edit: I forgot to include that I was looking for a way without having to create a separate branch. Vampire's solution is perfect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Temporarily put away uncommited changes in Subversion (a la "git-stash")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554278/temporarily-put-away-uncommited-changes-in-subversion-a-la-git-stash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio is just a specialised IntelliJ IDEA, so you can use its `Shelve Changes` functionality. Go to the `Version Control` tool window in AS, right click the changelist and select `Shelve Changes...`. Then do your build without your local changes and unshelve the changes afterwards.