# Is there a CLI command for stashing in git-svn?

Tags: git, svn, terminal, command, git-stash

Are there any CLI commands to stash the working copy using `git-svn`?

I saw this answer but I was wondering if there is any particular command for `git svn`:

[Temporarily put away uncommited changes in Subversion (a la "git-stash")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554278/temporarily-put-away-uncommited-changes-in-subversion-a-la-git-stash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `git-svn` your local copy is a Git repository. You can simply use `git stash` directly.